# Rdlc to PDF rendering slow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, pdf-generation, rdlc

We've been doing timing on some of our slow PDF reports on our asp.net mvc3 web app,

One in particular kinda blew our mind...

SQL - returned in a few nundred milliseconds
RDLC processing - a few hundred miliseconds
PDF generation - over 4 min

I've found this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ca45fcc4-be69-410f-aaed-19b65f279330/reporting-services-sp1-slow-on-pdf-render

and this:
[msdn page 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd353300%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Explaining how to address it by optimizing the RDLC, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't doing anything stupid in my c# code.

Here is the section that takes the RDLC and renders it as a PDF, it looks pretty simple, but am I doing it in the optimal way? Am I following best practices?

```
    // build the byte stream
    answerBytes = localViewer.Render(
        args.ReportType, args.DeviceInfoXML, out mimeType, out encoding, out fnameExt,
        out streamids, out warnings );

    // send out vars back to client.
    args.MineType = mimeType;
    args.FnameExt = fnameExt;
    // dispose of local viewer when complete
    localViewer.Dispose();

    netLogHdl.Trace( "Done PDF work " );
    return answerBytes;
```

PDF Generation is SOO Bad I feel like I must have dome something wrong...

P.S. here is more of the stack if it's needed

```
public byte[] ByteStreamPdf(ref ByteStreamReportArgsCV args)
    {
        //The DeviceInfo settings should be changed based on the reportType            
        //http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155397.aspx            
        string deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo>";
        deviceInfo += "<OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>";

        if (args.Landscape)
        {
            deviceInfo += "<PageWidth>11in</PageWidth><PageHeight>8.5in</PageHeight>";
        }
        else
        {
            deviceInfo += "<PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth><PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>";
        }

        deviceInfo += "<MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop><MarginLeft>1in</MarginLeft>";
        deviceInfo += "<MarginRight>1in</MarginRight><MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>";
        deviceInfo += "</DeviceInfo>";
        deviceInfo = "";

        args.DeviceInfoXML = deviceInfo;
        args.ReportType = "Pdf";
        return ByteStreamReport(ref args);
    }


public byte[] ByteStreamReport(ref ByteStreamReportArgsCV args)
        {
            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamids;
            string encoding;
            string fnameExt;
            string mimeType;
            byte[] answerBytes;
            LocalReport localViewer = new LocalReport();


            // enable external images... CR # 20338 JK
            localViewer.EnableExternalImages = true;

            // build the Report Data Source
            // open up your .rdlc in notepad look for <datasets>  section in xml
            // use what you find on the next line.
            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource(args.NameOfDatasetInRdlc, args.DataToFillReport);

            // set the report path and datasource
            IWebAccess webAccessHdl = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IWebAccess>();
            //next line was HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(args.RdlcPathAndFname); changed to use webaccess - EWB
            localViewer.ReportPath = webAccessHdl.GetMapPath(args.RdlcPathAndFname);
            localViewer.DataSources.Add(rds);

            // add parameters that rdlc needs
            if (args.RptParameters != null)
                localViewer.SetParameters(args.RptParameters);

            //Sub Report Task
            if (args.SubReportDataToFillReport != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < args.SubReportDataToFillReport.Length; i++)
                {
                    ReportDataSource subRds = new ReportDataSource(args.SubReportNameOfDatasetInRdlc[i],
                                                                   args.SubReportDataToFillReport[i]);
                    localViewer.DataSources.Add(subRds);
                }

                if (args.SubReportDataToFillReport.Length > 0)
                    localViewer.SubreportProcessing +=
                        LoadSubreportProcessingEventHandler;
            }

            //End of Sub Report Task

            // build the byte stream
            answerBytes = localViewer.Render(
                args.ReportType, args.DeviceInfoXML, out mimeType, out encoding, out fnameExt,
                out streamids, out warnings);

            // send out vars back to client.
            args.MineType = mimeType;
            args.FnameExt = fnameExt;
            // dispose of local viewer when complete
            localViewer.Dispose();
            return answerBytes;
        }
```

Comment: Hi Eric - I'm seeing the exact same issue. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: I don't remember if it was this specific issue, but we reduced the number of fields we passed in and processed in the RDLC, It turned out much faster to do all that pre processing stuff in c#, then pass the pre massaged data into the RDLC. Do the absolute minimum possible (like grouping) in the rdlc. All the fancy data transformation in the RLDC was very slow.

Comment: final source code about it? You use CLR 4.0 AppPool and ASP.NET 4.5 ?

Comment: It wasn't a source code change, we just changed the report and the objects passed in.. Instead of doing calculation in fields of the the report all we did was pass it the final answers for each field. This required more fields on the model but otherwise was no biggie code wise.